# Database version upgrade for java applications

Tags: java

We will have to update our databases version Oracle v11 to v19.
The database part itself doesn't matter for this discussion, because it will be made by our DBA's.
Besides having to upgrade the JDBC connectors' version and maybe changing how they are instantiated, what are the possible problems and refactors we might have to do?
The applications are in JAVA.

Comment: Have you visited Oracle's [FAQ](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/faq-jdbc.html)?

Comment: According to the FAQ, I'll have to upgrade all the projects JAVA version to at least 8.
I believe that it will cause a series of refactors on deprecated and/or unexistent packages and methods.
But I was expecting that someone had already gone through this kind of thing before and could share their experience on the subject.